# How would I print "bark" using python classes in this situation?

Tags: python, oop

How would I print "bark" using python classes.

```
class pet:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_age(self):
        return self.age

class dog(pet):

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super().__init__(name, age)

    def bark(self):
        print("bark")

max = pet("max", 5)

max.dog.bark()
```

Comment: `max = dog("max", 5)` `max.bark()`

Comment: pet has no bark method, you need a dog instance.

Answer (score 1):

To call the `dog` class's `bark` method, you need an instance of `dog`.

```
max = dog("max", 5)
max.bark()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
class pet:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_age(self):
        return self.age

class dog(pet):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super().__init__(name, age)

    def bark(self):
        print("bark")

my_pet = dog("max",3)

my_pet.bark()
```